# Do all Android phones have a minimum set of sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to find out about sensors in Android phones.

Do all/most phones have a basic set of sensors or do I have to look at the individual specifications to find what each supports. The specs I have looked at seem rather unclear as to what each phone actually provides.

I haven't been able to find even an out of date list of phones and their sensors, but if anyone can point me to one, I would be grateful.

I should have made it clear that I am looking for this information as my application may need a specific sensor or combination of sensors. If these are not generally available then the application may not be worth developing. In addition, it may be possible to use more than one combination of sensors to do the job, so information on what is likely to be available will aid development.

Comment: I suppose yes there are.

Comment: Don't know if all devices have min set of sensors, but considering the number of devices I think you shouldn't rely on that. Check if sensors are avaliable at runtime, or maybe there is a way to restrict set of abaliable devices in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Seems as if wasn't the only person to be asking this question. This question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402062/android-mandatory-sensors#_=_) appeared after mine, but has the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Android has no minimum hardware requirements for Android when it comes to sensors. The Android Compatibility Program states:

> Android 2.3 includes APIs for accessing a variety of sensor types. Devices implementations generally MAY omit these sensors, as provided for in the
>   following subsections.

The best way of going about it is to specify the sensors your app uses in your AndroidManifest.xml file, along with whether or not those sensors are required for the application to work. The android market uses the details of required sensors (and other hardware features) to hide the app from unsupported devices on the market.

Details of the different flags and how to use them can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

When you publish a draft of the app, you can see a list of all the devices which support the features requested.