# Android - mandatory sensors?

Tags: android, sensors

Is there a mandatory list for hardware on Android devices (e.g. magnetic field, distance)?

If not, which one are common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things are defined in the [Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD)](http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html).

[Here](http://source.android.com/compatibility/2.3/android-2.3.3-cdd.pdf) is the current one. Check out the hardware-sensors section [7.3.].
As far as I can see all sensors are optional.

Most devices are equipped with the following sensors:

- GPS
- Accelerometer
- Proximity sensor
- Magnetic field
- Light
- Gravity

*(from an [API viewpoint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html), some might be the same on a hardware basis)*